# How to redirect output terminal help documents of git (or any other) to a text file, which has bold font words in it?

Tags: bash, redirect, terminal, command, output

I'd like to redirect output the help documents of git to a text file, command like this:

```
git help clone > gitclone.txt
```

But i found that all the bold font words in the document, were wrote double times to my gitclone.txt.

i.e:

**NAME** in document, changes to NNAAMMEE in gitclone.txt

I dont know why this happens, can someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `col -b` to remove the backspaces.

```
git help clone | col -b > gitclone.txt
```